# Template overload resolution with multiple viable types

Tags: c++, templates

Here are 2 template functions for calculating max

```cpp
template<typename T>
auto max(T a, T b) {
  cout <<  "Calling 1\n";
  return b < a ? a : b;
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto max (T1 a, T2 b) {
  cout <<  "Calling 2\n";
  return b < a ? a : b;
}
```

If I call the max function as follows

```cpp
max(1, 2);
```

The first function (Calling 1) is selected. Why is that the case? Both 1 and 2 can match equally well in this case.

Comment: Side note: `max` with different types is not a good idea because of the signed unsigned conversion rules in C.  With the second version you would get  `max(-1,1U) == 0xFFFFFFFF` (or else, depending on the bitness of int). Probably you get a compiler warning, but the bug is inside the max function. The first max function (with same argument types) is safe (there the bug will be in the users code :-). Numerics in C/C++ is intuitive only at the superficial level.

Comment: @AndreasH.Thats an interesting insight. I agree, preventing accidental bugs in user code is generally more important that slight inconvenience of making users use static_cast

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the first `max` is *more specialized* as the second `max`.

What happens during template overload resolution is that the compiler instantiates both templates and then asks "Which one is more specialized?"

In a nutshell it asks, given overload A and overload B, "Can I instantiate B with the deduced type(s) from A, but not vice versa?" If so, then A is more specialized than B (we can go from A to B, but not back). It does the same thing the other way. If both can be instantiated from each other, it is ambiguous and a compiler error.

In reality, we don't use the *actual* type for `T` (`int` in this case), but some made-up type (["synthesized type"](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.func.order#3)).

In your case, the first template requires both types to be the same:

```
template<typename T>
auto max(T a, T b)
```

So we have `max<int>` (or `max<synthesized1>`)

Can we instantiate the second one given `synthesized1` for `T`? Sure thing, `T1 = synthesized1` and `T2 = synthesized1`.

Can we go the other way though?

The second template has *two* parameters, so it allows that `a` and `b` are different types, so it is more general. It gets instantiated with two synthesized types:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto max (T1 a, T2 b)
```

so, `max<synthesized2, synthesized3>`.

Can we instantiate the first `max<T>` with types `synthesized2` and `synthesized3`? Nope, it requires that `a` and `b` have the same type. Therefore the first template is more specialized, and the compiler chooses it.

Refer to [[temp.deduct.partial]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.partial) for standardese

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb for overload resolution in C++, more specialized versions are preferred over more generic versions. Since the second version can handle more general cases, the first version is preferred.